# SAX XMLParser not working

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I have followed multiple online tutorials on how to set up a SAX XML parser for the Android platform but none of them seem to work! Whats the problem? Heres my code:

Imports:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
```

This Code is in a method that I know gets called, but why doesent logcat show "TESTING"?

```
 try {
                URL XMLURL = new URL("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Crystallize+Lindsey+Stirling+Offical+Music+Video&orderby=relevance");
                SAXParserFactory SPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser SP = SPF.newSAXParser();

                DefaultHandler mainHandler = new DefaultHandler(){

                    @Override
                    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                            String qName, Attributes attributes)
                            throws SAXException {

                        if(localName.equals("Link")){

                            String possibleURL = attributes.getValue("href");
                            Log.i("TEST","TESTING");
                        }

                    }
                };

                SP.parse(new InputSource(XMLURL.openStream()),mainHandler);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Does your xml contain a tag named "Link"?  We might have a better chance of diagnosing this if you post the xml input.

Comment: Yes it does. Just open this [link](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Crystallize+Lindsey+Stirling+Offical+Music+Video&orderby=relevance) and hit CTRL-U in Firefox to view the page source after clicking the top result from the search. Even if you log from outside that if statement(so anytime the parser hits an object) you still get no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a namespace issue.

```
SAXParserFactory SPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser SP = SPF.newSAXParser();
```

is giving you a parser that doesn't properly handle namespaces.

If you change the startElement to check `qName` for the value "link", your code will work, but that's sort of a band-aid fix.

There *are* namespaces in this document, though this element is in the default namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom specified for the document.

You should tell the parser factory to give you a namespace-aware parser:

```
SAXParserFactory SPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SPF.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser SP = SPF.newSAXParser();
```

And then you'll get the expected result without changing the `startElement` method, except you do have to look for the right value, i.e., check for "link" instead of "Link".

Comment: I figured out what the problem was! I was trying to run this on the main thread and java didn't like that! Sorry for my mistake as I am very new to Android development. Thanks a lot for you patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat for a big chunk of yellow text. It may inform you about any errors that crashed the SAX parser.

Comment: It probably didn't crash, and simply didn't find a match.